# C Language - how do I fix my Binary Search Function in my code?

Tags: c, search, file-io, binary-search, file-read

This is what I have

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void print(int a[], int size);     
void sort (int a[], int size);     
void swap (int* a, int *b);     
int search(int searchValue, int a[], int size);     

int main()     
{     
    float avg = 0;     
    float sum = 0;     
    float arrayr [50];     
    int i = 0;     
    int j = 0;     
    int a;     
    int b;     
    int sid = 1;     
    int number;     
    int size = sizeof(arrayr) / sizeof(int);     
    sort(arrayr,size);     
    print(arrayr,size);     

    FILE* fp;
    fp =  fopen("A7data.txt","r");
    if(fp==0)
    {
        printf("File does not exist");
        exit(1);
    }

        for (i=0; i<50; i++)
    {
        fscanf(fp,"%d %*d %*d %*d %*d %*d %*d %*d %*d %*d %*d %*d %*d",&arrayr[i]);
    }
    sort(arrayr,50);
        //printf("%d",a[i]);
        printf("Enter student ID -> ");
        scanf("%d",&sid);
        if (sid == 0)
        {
        printf("%d is not a valid student ID\n",search(number,arrayr,size));
        }
        else
        {
        printf("%d is a valid student ID\n",search(number,arrayr,size));
        }

return 0;
}

void print (int a[], int size)
{
    int i;
    int sid = 0;
    int number;
    int arrayr;
    //for (i = 0; i < size; i++)

    //printf("\n");
}

void sort (int a[], int size)
{
    int i,j;
        for (i = 0; i < size - 1; i++)
    {
        for (j = i; j < size; j++)
    {
        if (a[j]<a[i]) swap(&a[i],&a[j]);
    }
}
}

void swap (int* a, int *b)
{
    int temp;
    temp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = temp;
}

 int search(int searchValue, int a[], int size)
{
        int low, high, middle;
        int sid;
        low = 0;
        high = size-1;
        while (low <= high)
{
    middle = (low + high) / 2;
    if (searchValue < a[middle])
    {
        high = middle - 1;
    }
    else if (searchValue > a[middle])
    {
        low = middle + 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return middle;
    }
}
return sid;
}
```

and this is my output

```
 Enter student ID -> 20119084

 2001840454 is a valid student ID

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 2.816 s
Press any key to continue.
```

The assignment directions are
Reading in a copy of the Assignment 7 student data file.  It has exactly 50 records.  Store the student IDs (column 1 in the file) into an array.
 Sort the array in ascending order.
 Write a binary search function to demonstrate the following.

56874837 is a valid student ID.
56874838 is not a valid student ID.

http://voyager.deanza.edu/~bentley/ass7data.html 
This is the data file we are supposed to read

My code isn't showing the correct output, and I think it is because my binary search function or something in my functions is wrong. I'm not sure what I am doing incorrectly since my output isn't showing up like the directions display.

Comment: can you at least confirm that it is sorted? via printout?

Comment: Why are you trying to sort and search an array of floats with functions that work with arrays of ints???

Comment: You are reading value in `sid` as `scanf("%d",&sid);` but passing `number` to `search()`.

Comment: your fscanf function should be `fscanf(fp,"%d",&arrayr[i]);`

Comment: My mistake, I replaced "float arrayr[50]" with "int arrayr[50]"

Comment: You fix it by figuring out what's wrong with it and  writing it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you pass `number` to `search` but `number` was never set. For the rest, put some effort into it, using a debugger or IDE or `printf` statements to figure out what your code is doing ... from there you can figure out how to correct it.